# Convention for a controller that generates a view from several models

Tags: model-view-controller, sails.js, controllers

In Sails.js, a route is set up against a controller method which can render a view. For the most part, this is straightforward, i.e. you could set up a `GET /users` route that points to `UserController.find` (which is usually set up automatically anyway).

However, say the home page of a blog renders the 10 most recent posts in the main section and a column with a list of authors and categories. The controller method has to fetch posts, authors, and categories before rendering the view and sending it back to the client. Clearly, a method like this doesn't really belong in `PostController`, `AuthorController`, or `CategoryController`.

What's the best thing to do in this situation? Create a controller for rendering views that rely on data from multiple models? Is there a good name for such a controller?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would do (this is purely opinion-based) is creating a `PageController` and create an action for each page you'd want.

For your home page example you can create a `home` action, get whatever you need and then render it with `res.ok()` (if everything is fine).

Another option would be to use `Sails` as a pure API and use HTTP requests (Ajax) or sockets to get your data in JSON. If you want to do so, I'd advise you to use a front end framework such as Angular, Ember, React...

By the way you could also create actions rendering HTML in your existing controllers and create a route to hit them through Ajax requests and just print them in your page. I'd prefer the 2nd solution because it takes full advantage of the Blueprint API (you don't need new controller or action whatsoever).

Comment: Thanks! I do prefer a pure API, but I'm building a blog that will have a SEO-friendly frontend and Angular-based backend. I think this is probably the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

As Yann pointed out, this answer has to be a little opinionated. It seems that you are using the views system and not building a single page application. For the home page, I would go for an `IndexController.js` file with a `home(req, res)` action.

```js
// api/controllers/IndexController.js
module.exports = {
  home: function (req, res) {
    // Retrieve all the information you need
    // Take care about managing the asynchronous calls before rendering the view
    return res.view('homepage');
  }
};
```

Declare the route

```js
// config/routes.js
module.exports.routes = {
  'get /': 'IndexController.home'
}
```

Create the view in `views/homepage.ejs`.